# In MVC, MVP and MVVM the model could it be a collection of entities?

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework, mvvm, model, mvp

I try to understand what a Model is. I already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4579038/196526).

In MVC, MVP and MVVM the model could it be a collection of entities?

Comment: I ask this question because I see a lot of developers are modeling (UML) the Model in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. A Model is all what describes a data used by business logic.

Ofthen in MVVM Model is encapsulated by the appropriate ViewModel itself. You need to separate a Model layer from ViewModel in case when different models could be handled by a single ViewModel.

Comment: -1: no, model is a layer that contains all of the business logic. Model is **not** data.

Comment: @tereško: thanks for your comment. I would say it depends, in MVVM model sometimes is not introduced at all so ViewModel represents both logic and model

Comment: Which interpretation of "viewmodel"? Originally the pattern was used for cases when you either have no control over implementation of model (think, some SAP backend system) or/and view. And the viewmodel was in the place of controller, where it was responsible for translating data from one to other. The **other** one is the ASP.NET MVC (mis)interpretation, where they took [presentation object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) concept (Fowler has this annothing habit of adding "model" to everything) and called it "viewmodel".

Answer (score 1):

Sure it could, I think of a model as a collection of properties that are used to render a view.  No more, no less.  If you need a collection of entities to render the view then it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In all of the patterns "Model" is not a class or object. Model is a layer - an intangible  construction, which (in this particular case) consists several groups of structures.

The main parts of model are:

- [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) (or in some places called: domain entities, model objects, business objects)
- storage abstractions
- services (for "application logic" - interaction between domain objects and storage abstractions)

Having multiple "models" is a misconception that was introduced by Rails (rapid prototyping framework for ruby), which, for sake of some simplification, decided to call their [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) instances "models" and refer to their templates as "views".